# Joomla external URL redirect on successful login

Tags: authentication, joomla, redirect

Im looking to override the default joomla login redirect and use an external url on succesful login (which currently doesn't seem possible within the default joomla setup).

I found this support doc:

https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_redirect_users_after_a_successful_login%3F

The code I would add would be as follows.. correct?

```
$redirectUrl = urlencode(base64_encode("http://subdomain.mydomain.com"));  
$joomlaLoginUrl = 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login';
$finalUrl = $joomlaLoginUrl . $redirectUrl;
```

But im not sure where to add this code, in the support doc it says 'in your Administration back end from your custom code'?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default login module of joomla loads menu item that are published in joomla. So you can create a new menu item using the type "System links -> external url" Put your external url in that menu item.

That menu item will now show up in the module administration. You just need to select it.

You could as well modify the php of the module. The module is called mod_login in the folder modules. You might also consider creating a new module. Download all the files, do your modifications, change the mod_login.xml, in order to change the name of the  module, add your name as well etc. Zip the whole folder and then install it through the normal joomla installer. Like this you will not have upgrade issues.

The file to modify is called helper.php in mod_login folder. On line 45 you can edit:

```
return base64_encode($url);
```

And change it to:

```
return base64_encode("http://your.url.com");
```